# How do I find songs that I've hearted/favorited in Apple Music?

Tags: music, music-streaming

If I'm listening to a song and I click/tap the ♥︎ icon, is there a list of these anywhere?

I know if I `Add to My Music` I can get to these by making a smart playlist where `Loved` `is true`. But about for songs that I didn't add to my music?